# How to give HTML table cells same width as the cell with the biggest content?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/8D5Rk/1/

What i want is all the other cells to be the same width as the one with VSF05 in it (in this case, the biggest cell).
Weirdly enough i couldn't find a solution to this online.

Also,i would like to give the second, empty table to have the same cell width as the biggest one of the table above.

HTML

```
<table border="1" style="margin-left:20px;font-size:80%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
<th>8</th>
<th>9</th>
<th>10</th>
<th>11</th>
<th>12</th>
<th>13</th>
<th>14</th>
<th>15</th>
<th>16</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1 S</th>
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td>
<a onclick="alert("VSF05 ")" href="#">VSF05 </a>
</td>
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


    <br>
<table border="1" style="margin-left:20px;font-size:70%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
<th>8</th>
<th>9</th>
<th>10</th>
<th>11</th>
<th>12</th>
<th>13</th>
<th>14</th>
<th>15</th>
<th>16</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2 V</th>
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First you should close the `td` tags.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think CSS alone can do this.

**jQuery:**

```
//max is 0 (not yet known)
    var max = 0;
//find the max.  searching 1 row is enough --@Alexis Wilke
    $('tr').first().find('td').each(function(k, v) {
        var currentWidth = parseFloat($(this).css('width'));
//if currentWidth is bigger than the latest found max, update the max
        if (currentWidth > max)
        {
            max = currentWidth;
        }

    });
//set width to max
    $('td').css('width', max);
```

Comment: One point, though: you search the entire table when just one row is enough since all the columns have the same width in all the rows... If you have one row of headers (`th`) that's really easy. If you don't you should first get the first `tr` and then calculate the max from the `td` in that row.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your width requirement for your tables is, but you can use CSS:

```
table 
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbBQA/)

---

If you don't want your cell content extended out passed its cell, you can use `overflow-x` on the td.

```
table td 
{
    overflow-x: hidden; // hides content if the cell isn't wide enough
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2XMgR/)

OR

```
table td 
{
    overflow-x: auto; // only shows scrollbar when necessary
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/27MdM/)

OR

```
table td 
{
    overflow-x: scroll; // all cells show scrollbars, not ideal
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/48bWg/)

Comment: That won't fit the width of the max element. if the (total width)/(# of cells in a row) is greater than the width of the contents of the largest cell, it won't fit width to the contents, it will exceed the contents. See by dragging the center bar on the fiddle to the left.

Comment: @chiliNUT If OP specifies a fixed width it will. You know something that will contain all the data?

Comment: @chiliNUT - I know, that's why I was asking what the width requirement was.  Regardless, if his width requirement isn't wide enough, js won't fix it either.  There is another solution though.

Comment: You can't assume the width will be fixed. If it is, then fine. If it is not explicit that width is fixed, I always assume it is variable. That's where the JS comes in.

Comment: I didn't assume, I stated I didn't know what the width requirement was.  Regardless, javascript is only beneficial if the table width is wider than the total number of cells * max cell content width.  If it's less than that and causes the content in the cells to exceed their boundaries, what good will javascript do?  You'd still have to modify the overflow at that point too. So using a fixed width one of with the overflow-x options is the best way to go.

Comment: That said, to achieve the variable width you say I can't assume, he could wrap the tables with a DIV that has variable width, leaving the tables at a fixed width of 100%, a fixed table-layout, and one of the overflow-x options, and he'd still be solving the issue without javascript.

Comment: Ah yeah if its in a container div that can manage the variable width of the table, then that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your table working.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table { table-layout: fixed; }
td { width: (100/16)%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
<th>8</th>
<th>9</th>
<th>10</th>
<th>11</th>
<th>12</th>
<th>13</th>
<th>14</th>
<th>15</th>
<th>16</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1 S</th>
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
<td><a onclick="alert("VSF05 ")" href="#">VSF05 </a></td>
<td style="background-color:#E6E6E6">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You alert won't work. 
Your code is :

```
<a onclick="alert("VSF05")" href="#">VSF05 </a>
```

but for your alert, you're using double-quotes twice, which is causing the alert to not do it's job. Instead, do this :

```
<a onclick"alert('VSF05')" href="#">VSF05</a>
```

It make look subtle and it is.  I've used double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside.

Comment: It's certainly a good idea to let the user know that he has a bug in his HTML code, but that does not answer the question.